# WebDAV vs. SDK for accessing the Exchange 2003 calendar

Tags: c#, sdk, calendar, exchange-server, webdav

I'm trying to figure out how to access the calendar of Exchange 2003 from a remotely hosted ASP.NET/C# page (I only need to read and display calendar appointments/meetings etc.). As I understand it, I'm mainly down to two options - using WebDAV or the Exchange SDK.

I have found some good examples of how to use WebDAV, although I've not yet gotten it to work properly. I haven't looked too close at the SDK yet, and before I spend time on that, I'm wondering if anyone's got any pros and cons with the two different techniques, and any suggestions on which I should go for?

Any useful SDK links would also be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say there are a number of ways to do this, but webdav is the best bet, as it is supported by MS from managed code where as CDO tend to have greyer shades of support depending on what you are doing. 
If you are new to webdav it may be an idea a looking at some of the wrapper classes around as that could speed your dev up. I have used a 3rd party one
http://www.independentsoft.de/webdavex/index.html their support is lighting fast !

The MSDN documentation is probally the starting point 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa143161(EXCHG.65).aspx

here are others that i have had booked marked before show examples

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa123570.aspx
http://www.msexchange.org/articles/Access-Exchange-2000-2003-Mailbox-WebDAV.html
http://blogs.technet.com/kclemson/archive/2004/01/23/62247.aspx
http://blog.mbcharbonneau.com/2006/10/26/using-net-and-webdav-to-access-an-exchange-server/